# ODBC and SQL Server 2008: Can't use prepared statements?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo, odbc

OK, so I **cannot** get this to work (either):

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?");
odbc_execute($stmt, array($username));
$user = odbc_fetch_object($stmt);


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execut(array($username));
$user = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

Both return the same errors:

> Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL
>   state HY000 in SQLExecute in
>   user.php on line 24

Anyone know if it's possible to solve this, or are prepared statements off the table? If so, how should guard against SQL injections?

Comment: I added a try/catch block - does that output any helpful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use the fetchObject method but how about this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $username);
try{
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
       // Do whatever.
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

I also notice the single quotes around your question mark ('?'), they shouldn't be there.

In order to use the try/catch stuff you'll need to include this when you create your PDO connection:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And you might want to add this as well:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE); // Try to use the driver's native prepared statements.
```

Comment: Holy cheeseburgers! What a reversion! I'm sorry that edit happened, but the fixed sql are the ones that elicit the errors. I'm sorry about the confusion!

Comment: So do you still get the same error if you use the prepare and bindValue method I outline above rather than using the fetchObject method?

Comment: When I try bindvalue() i get absolutely nothing. No warnings/error and a NULL result.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a try/catch block - does this echo out any helpful information?