# PHP, ODBC, and SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

How does one prevent against SQL injections when using ODBC to connect to a MS SQL Server?  `odbc_prepare()` doesn't work ([see my open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407477/odbc-and-sql-server-2008-cant-use-prepared-statements)) due to bugs unixODBC, and there is no `_escape` or `_quote` function for ODBC, either.

Additionally, PDO has a bad, 6 year-old bug where if a result returns a NULL in **any** column, the entire resultset comes back null (at least when connected to MSSQL over ODBC).

So what can I possibly do to guard against SQL injections?

Comment: whats the issue with the odbc_prepare() ?

Comment: @sheldonCooper It's detailed in the linked question; it errors out.

Comment: Ya I saw that. I have suggested a solution for that.

Comment: I don't want to appear unhelpful (or unrealistic), but if your current software stack has known bugs and if those bugs are critical for your scenario then you should at least evaluate other options. Using PHP on Windows would give you access to a [native driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc299381.aspx) with PDO support, although I know that a change like that may not be possible in your situation.

Comment: It's for a shortterm project for a very large client unable to change. I'm just a contractor, they wouldn't listen to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is an old question and `odbc_prepare()` is pretty much deprecated.

What you should do is use PDO instead:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Use the MSSQL driver's native prepared statements.
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```

This should work.

Comment: +1 for setting `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false`.
The simplest way to prevent SQL injections when using prepared statements.