# Php pdo unixOBDC to sqlserver 2008: String data, length mismatch when execute prepared stmt

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, prepared-statement, unixodbc

I have the following setup: Apache / php 5.3 / pdo with odbc with installed Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux on server.

My script rises an error with the following stacktrace when trying to execute a statement:

```
(UTC) 2013-12-16 12:07:40: Thrown exception log ->
'Error message: SQLSTATE[22026]: String data, length mismatch: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, length mismatch (SQLExecute[0] at /tmp/pear/temp/PDO_ODBC/odbc_stmt.c:133)
 Arisen in Core_Db->select(array (
      0 =>
         'SELECT  *
          FROM    TMS.dbo.TEST_user
          WHERE   email = ? AND status_id = ?',
      1 => 
         array (
             0 => 'support@mail.com',
             1 => 2
         ),
))
```

For testing I use php 5.3 on windows with pdo sqlsrv and nothing went wrong there.

Connection code is

```
        // for unixODBC (production)
        if (DB_DRIVER == 'odbc') {
            $this->_link = new PDO(
                "odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=" . DB_HOST . ";"
                . "PORT=" . DB_PORT . ";DATABASE=" . DB_NAME . ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=" . DB_LOGIN . ";"
                . "PWD=" . DB_PASSWD . ";"
            );
        // for sqlsrv (development)
        } else {
            $this->_link = new PDO(
                "sqlsrv:Server=" . DB_HOST . "," . DB_PORT . ";Database=" . DB_NAME,
                DB_LOGIN,
                DB_PASSWD
            );
        }
        $this->_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

There is some recommendation regarding this issue: [ODBC and SQL Server 2008: Can't use prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407477/odbc-and-sql-server-2008-cant-use-prepared-statements). But I can't check it. When I try to add an attribute in production, the script rises the following error:

```
(UTC) 2013-12-16 13:19:44: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

**UPDATED 2013-12-18**

```
// unixODBC connection
$this->_link = new PDO(
    "odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;"
    . "PORT=1433;DATABASE=TMS;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;",
    DB_LOGIN,
    DB_PASSWD,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, // this attr is recognized by ODBC
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false // but if this is added ODBC throws PDOException with message "driver does not support setting attributes"
    )
 );
```

String's transfer from ODBC to Client leads to string's corruption  while prepared statement is used. So I only guess the matter is in PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> (UTC) 2013-12-16 13:19:44: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support
>   this function: driver does not support setting attributes

is telling you that this line:

```
$this->_link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

is invalid. Instead, do this:

```
$driver_options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE);

if (DB_DRIVER == 'odbc'){ // for unixODBC (production)
    $dsn = 'odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='. DB_HOST .';PORT='. DB_PORT .';DATABASE='. DB_NAME .';PROTOCOL=TCPIP;';
    $this->_link = new PDO($dsn, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWD, $driver_options);
}else{ // for sqlsrv (development)
    $this->_link = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:Server=" . DB_HOST . "," . DB_PORT . ";Database=" . DB_NAME,
        DB_LOGIN,
        DB_PASSWD
    );
}
```

Comment: No, the error occurs only when I apply $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

Comment: @Eugeny - I have updated my answer. You cannot use the `setAttribute()` function, you have to set that option when you create the PDO object.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error. It does not allow to set any attribute except for PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE even when PDO is being created.

Comment: @Eugeny - can you edit your question and show your updated code? Please include the part where you're trying to set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.

Comment: Regarding this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441721/microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-on-redhat-linux-with-php-gives-an-er) and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506128/prepared-pdo-statement-and-ms-sql) and other else - this is a driver's bug.

Comment: @Eugeny - Ah, thank you for the links. If the Microsoft driver won't work for you would FreeTDS be an option?

Comment: We have some troubles/limitations with making php with pdo_dblib on the server. Also we tried EasySoft sql odbc solution, but it also has unexpected bugs with execution of prepared queries. I think I have to change database

Comment: I got a callback from EasySoft concerned this subject. It seems that all the fault of php 64-bit application which is run on 64bit Debian. PHP fails SQLLEN / SQLULEN sizes, building them like 32 bit ones. Thus output strings (from php to driver) are going to be corrupted.

Comment: @Eugeny - thank you for letting me know what the problem is. I hope you can find a solution (perhaps moving to a 32-bit environment?).